# Max and min of N numbers, using do-while

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'm learning C language and I'm trying to do the following exercise: Take in input N numbers and print the maximum and the minimum, without using for loop and array. I tried lots of times but I always get stuck.

I tried to compare first 2 numbers and assigning them to max and min variable, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Could you provide your code sample and the real use case you trying to implement/solve?

Comment: "without using for loop"? - Does that mean a "(do) while loop" is permitted?

Comment: Is N known at compile-time? Or does the user input N at run-time?

Comment: I only wrote the first part where I say how much number I have to take, I haven't wrotten the second part because I don't know how to make it functional

Comment: The user input N at run-time, but that isn't a problem

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, a do while loop is permitted

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60678273/edit) your question and wrap your code in code-blocks: `\`\`\``. Make sure to put a newline between the triple-backticks and the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop(I guess you are taking input with while) you need to compare max and min values with given input. At the beginning set the minimum  to the [actual limit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits), which is INT_MAX (if the data type is int) or UINT_MAX (if the data type is unsigned int)and max =0.Then after taking input n you can compare like

```
 if(n>max) max=n; 
 if(n<min)min=n
```

After taking all inputs your max will be the maximum number and min will be the minimum number.
P.S  I am taking into consideration user can only enter positive numbers.

Comment: Instead of setting the minimum value to an arbitrary big number like "1000000", wouldn't it be better to set it to the [actual limit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits), which is `INT_MAX` (if the data type is `int`) or `UINT_MAX` (if the data type is `unsigned int`). If the data type is signed, then the maximum value should be set to `INT_MIN`, that way negative values can also be handled.

Comment: Thank you it is better solution!

Comment: Done.Thanks for correction

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: okay i'm gonna change my answer)

Comment: Now everything is correct i guess)

Comment: @subhanceo: Yes, the only thing that could be missing from your answer is how negative numbers should be handled. But since the question was not clear in that respect and you explicitly mentioned that you were assuming that only positive numbers were being entered, your answer is ok. Ideally, you would also mention how to handle negative numbers and would also mention setting `max` to `INT_MIN`, but I'm not sure if that is worth the effort, especially since the OP has accepted your answer and has expressed no interest in handling negative numbers and the question has been closed anyway.

Comment: @subhanceo: I think I will not delete my first comment, because it contains extra information on handling negative numbers that you did not incorporate into your answer. As stated before, I don't think it is worth editing your answer, so I guess it is best that I just leave my comment, even if I originally intended to delete it later.